# How the hash Code method is calculating the value?

Tags: java

The hashCode() method return a serie of numbers, but two different objects can have the same result.
So how this function is really calculating that value,internally ?
Is that related to memory case, and what's the element included in th calculation?

Comment: The identity hash code (i.e. the value returned by `Object.hashCode()` and by other classes that don't override that method and provide their own implementation) is implementation specific and what exactly it is depends on the JVM implementation.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Object javadoc, hashCode method may returns the object's address in memory at some point in time

> The hashCode may or may not be implemented as some function of an
>   object's memory address at some point in time

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Remember that this method is useful to compare whether two or more or object are the same together with `equals` method,but you can override this method to return the same hashcode if some attributes (e.g PKs) are the same although them are different objects in memory

Comment: The Javadoc you link to is for the obsolete Java 6 version. Even that one says "This is typically implemented by converting the internal address of the object into an integer, **but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language**." This sentence is removed in later versions. It is wrong to say "hashCode returns the object's address in memory." In fact, the garbage collector can reallocate an object to a different address yet its hashCode will remain the same. You shouldn't use hashCode to check if two objects are the same - do `if (obj1 == obj2)` instead.

Comment: `if (obj1 == obj2)` works only if you care if the objects are in fact the same physical object.  If you want logical equality you need to use `o1.equals(o2)`.  These objects may not be the same object, but might be logically equal (e.g. String, Number, etc).